# Flash CS5, make the image scaling smoother

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have a problem where the images look a little pixelated because they have been scaled down alot, just need a way to make everything appear smoother.

I need the game I'm making to look high quality and also work at different resolutions so when I made all the graphics I made them massive and same for the stage size in flash.

The stage size is 2000*1500 and it's being scaled down to 800*600 which is an exact ratio, I didn't expect to see pixelization when scaling the images DOWN, that's why I made them so large.

If there's no options for smoothing things out, then does anyone know the best option for swapping images at run-time? This way I can have pre-made images for all the most popular resolutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using bitmaps, try smoothing and pixelsnapping:

```
image.smoothing = true;         
image.pixelSnapping = "never";
```

If you have library images (bitmaps), try changing "Allow Smoothing" and "Compression"

[image]

If you want to automate this you can use JSFL:
http://mrsteel.wordpress.com/2007/06/12/flash-jsfl-script-allow-smoothing-on-all-bitmaps-in-library/

Comment: Thanks, is there a way that I can do this for the whole stage. Because the images are all being used in buttons, and they are all loaded into the stage automatically by the IDE

Comment: I just found that I can set the smoothing from the IDE by going to the properties of an image. But I can't see anything to set pixel snapping.

Comment: Use this JSFL to apply smoothing on all bitmaps in the library. http://mrsteel.wordpress.com/2007/06/12/flash-jsfl-script-allow-smoothing-on-all-bitmaps-in-library/

Comment: Be careful with the loseless images though, you will get bigger files because they are not compressed.

Comment: Yeah nice One :). I used lossless on a few of the images but not most. Thanks for your help

Comment: another tip to help scaling issues is to make your image sizes the power of 2, i.e.: 8x8, 16x16, 32x32, 64x64, etc